# The meaning of sub-competence

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of sub-competence? I've searched everywhere but I couldn't find a thing

Comment: Could you provide more context and explain how you have seen the term used?

Answer (score 1):

sub-competence (noun) =

The roots of this saying are in the French language, 'la sous-compétence'.

The term is often used in the context of pedagogy. It means those skills that are below, being part of, the most important skill.

So, for example, to be able to write, you need to know the alphabet > knowing the alphabet is sub-competence of the competence of writing.

Comment: Hi Pirita, do you have a source for this you can link to?

Comment: For example, *The last [sub-competence](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sub-competence+within+the+leading%22) **within the leading unit of competence** focuses on how and when project managers are using their influencing skills to manipulate the outcome of the project.* But it's hardly the kind of derived form you'd expect to find in many *English* dictionaries (but I suspect the French "equivalent" is far more common in that language).

Answer (score -1):

Usually you would see **[incompetent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incompetent)**, which is a combination of "*competere*" (think *compete*, and fitness or match) and "*in-*" the standard issue negating prefix (e.g., *in*valid, *in*complete, *im*precise [the bilabial phoneme comes into play here because of the *p*]).

I'm no linguist, so I cannot say whether sub-competent has literary precedent. However, from it's composition, I would define it as such:

> **sub-competent** (adj): below or beneath the necessary level of competence.

Which is basically *incompetent*. The only difference I would suppose would be that *incompetent* refers to a generally absolute level of inability; i.e., you cannot do it *at all*; whereas *sub-competent* would imply that you can do it to some degree, and it may be a skillful level, even, but it is not sufficient to complete the task at hand. I would note that this semantic line is so gray that it may not at this time be linguistically productive to use this term.

Comment: No. 'Sub-' here (with sub-competence) is used in the hierarchical 'subset', 'subcontractor' sense rather than the pejorative 'subnormal', 'substandard' sense.